# How to initialize a static variable and set various value for it?

Tags: dart

In java, if you want to initialize a static variable once, you can write code in Static Initialization Block just like this:

```
abstract class Dummy {
    static final Map<String, object> cache = new HashMap();

    static {
        cache.add('foo', new Foo());
        cache.add('bar', new Bar());
    }
}
```

Here I want to ask if there have a similar way in Dart? What is the best coding practice in Dart programming?

```
abstract class Dummy {
  static final Map<String, dynamic> cache = <String, dynamic>{};
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is no static initialization block in dart, but there are some other approaches you could take here.

Firstly, if all you want to do is add a few items to a map, you can just use map literal syntax:

```dart
abstract class Dummy {
  static final Map<String, dynamic> cache = <String, dynamic>{
    'foo': Foo(),
    'bar': Bar(),
  };
}
```

Also if you just want to initialize a static value by calling a few methods on it, you can use [cascade notation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation) `..`, which for this specific example would look like this:

```dart
abstract class Dummy {
  static final Map<String, dynamic> cache = <String, dynamic>{}
    ..['foo'] = Foo()
    ..['bar'] = Bar();
}
```

The above is using cascade to call the `[]=` operator on the map instance, but you can call any method on the map instance using cascade. For example, I could also call the remove method:

```dart
abstract class Dummy {
  static final Map<String, dynamic> cache = <String, dynamic>{}
    ..['foo'] = Foo()
    ..['bar'] = Bar()
    ..remove('foo');
}
```

If you need to do something more complex you could also use an immediately invoked function literal `() {} ()`.

```dart
abstract class Dummy {
  static final Map<String, dynamic> cache = () {
    final result = <String, dynamic>{};
    result['foo'] = Foo();
    result['bar'] = Bar();
    return result;
  } ();
}
```